# Oracle Database Deployment

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I created a table in an Oracle database on my personal computer.

Then linked it with a Java Application and I am using that table/database to save all the data from the application.

But when I deploy my .jar file and run it from another system, that database is not installed on it.

Can anyone please tell me or guide me what I am suppose to do? In order for the database and the application to work on other systems too.

Thanks

Comment: install the oracle client on the other system, and create proper TNS entries to point to the correct database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'd need some options in your program to allow the user to configure which database server they want to use.

It would be up to them to deploy a server and provision it correctly before they could use your program.  Instructions on doing so would be included in the setup documentation for your program.

It's also possible for your program to be able to setup a database on a remote Oracle instance automatically.  You would implement an option to allow them to `CREATE DATABASE` on a configured Oracle instance, which would run provisioning scripts to create all the necessary tables, views, sprocs, etc.

Since these steps create a lot of friction in deploying and using your program, you should also ask yourself if you *really* need a SQL database for your program.  If it's just single user with a small amount of data, you could check into some sort of local DB that runs in proc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, this cleared a lot of things.